# Unable to delete the file "could not locate file path"

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am unable to delete this file. Tried multiple things from youtube but it didn't work. Tried to ran cmd as admin and tried deleting it, but no luck.
Tried restarting.
Tried to rename it as well but could not, same message.

- *there WAS a folder with name "This war of mine". i deleted that folder .. and somehow it started showing as file with a dot*
- *Tried rm command from live kali linux.. linux too can't find the file*

  *File Extensions property is set to visible in folder options.*

[image]

Tried this but:

[image]

Comment: Boot the PC to different OS like Linux live, mount the Windows Drive where the file reside, and then delete from there and this will ensure nothing with the Windows OS can keep it opened. Done and next!!

Comment: I do not want to dual boot my machine to delete just this file. Any other way ? Can we do this using some VM ?

Comment: no, windows 10 is on my system and file is on win 10. I have ubuntu vm in it.

Comment: Here's the instructions you want to follow for the Windows GUI tool https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732037(v=ws.11).aspx and find what has this file open and kill that. Just go to **Computer Management** and then click on **Shared Folders** and then **Open Files**. Have everything off apps and VM wise, or try deleting it in safe mode if needed.

Comment: That extra dot has me wondering what kind of funk you have going here. Try DEL D:\Games\this*.* from an administrative command prompt.

Comment: @Appleoddity tried that and see the updated Qs. please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, tried [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

Tried deleting the file > Failed

Tried renaming the file > success

deleted the renamed file > success

Comment: Sak, I missed the obvious. You've got some file corruption. I know you solved the issue but run chkdsk /f so you can make sure the files are in good shape. Maybe that's not it, but it was sure the obvious thing to suggest that I missed.

Comment: Ran that before using 7zip, result came fine. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 solutions you can try :

1) Try to delete it with cmd. [del D:......] 

2) If you can copy the    file then copy it to any other folder and then try to del.

 
3) Create    a bootable ubuntu pendrive and then boot with it then goto the    destination and del it.

Comment: tried all those methods.. get the same message popup. I actually deleted the folder with that name... and somehow it started showing as file with a dot.

Comment: Tried rm command from live kali linux.. linux too can't find the file

Comment: Are other file in that folder working? @Sak

Comment: there WAS a folder with name "This war of mine". i deleted that folder .. and  somehow it started showing as file with a dot ...